# What is the recommended way to call a javascript function from C# using the WinForms GeckoFX control?

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, geckofx

The questions says it all. I have everything wired up and know how to send messages from the browser html to c#, but not the other way.

I should be able to do something like:

```
browserControl.JSCall("myFunction('Dave','Smith');");
```

...and in the web code:

```
   function myFunction(firstName, lastName) {
       $("#mydiv").text(firstName + ' ' + lastName);
   }
```

Thanks - Dave

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Navigate:

```
browserControl.Navigate("javascript:void(myFunction('Dave','Smith'))");
```

Note, I find that the code isn't actually run until the application event loop executes. If that's a problem for you, you might be able to follow the Navigate call with

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

Make sure you consider the [dangers of calling DoEvents explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents).

Answer (score 2):

I know about AutoJSContext class so there is no need for passing javascript to Navigate().

```
    string outString = "";
    using (Gecko.AutoJSContext java = new Gecko.AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.JSContext))
    {
          java.EvaluateScript(@"window.alert('alert')", out outString );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dear @SturmCoder and @DavidCornelson are right.
but it seems that for **version 60.0.24.0**

**geckoWebBrowser1.JSCall()**

and

**Gecko.AutoJSContext()** which accepts **geckoWebBrowser1.JSContext**

are absolete and instead of **geckoWebBrowser1.JSContext** you should write **geckoWebBrowser1.Window**

and for me this codes works :

```
string result = "";
using (Gecko.AutoJSContext js= new Gecko.AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.Window))
{
    js.EvaluateScript("myFunction('Dave','Smith');", out result);
}
```

or even if the website has jQuery you can run like this :

```
string result = "";
using (Gecko.AutoJSContext js= new Gecko.AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.Window))
{
    js.EvaluateScript(@"alert($('#txt_username').val())", out result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `Navigate` method, you have this another workaround:

```
var script = geckofx.Document.CreateElement("script");
script.TextContent = js;
geckofx.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head").First().AppendChild(script);
```