# How Can Execute Javascript Commands via GeckoFX

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I try to execute a javascript command like alert('test message') via GeckoFX and C# 
but I can not.

I try without results with Navigate and with ExecuteCommand

My code is

```
    int i=0;    
    GeckoWebBrowser webBrowser
    webBrowser.Navigate("alert('"+i.ToString()+"');");
    webBrowser.ExecuteCommand("alert('" + i.ToString() + "');");
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use AutoJSContext to run javascript with geckofx.

Something like:

```
GeckoWebBrowser browser = ....;

using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(browser.JSContext))
{                               
   string result;
   context.EvaluateScript("3 + 2;", out result)
}
```

[See EvaluateScript unittests](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-21.0/src/2ad19599be1eecc0780e6c82d1ea2eaf8b565a6f/GeckofxUnitTests/GeckoWebBrowserTests.cs?at=default) for more info and examples.

If you are using a super old version of geckofx you may need to get a later version - [geckofx](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx)

Comment: I am using version 16.0.0.2

Comment: @Tom I know this is old, but Im trying to use this code and I have an error. 'Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser does not contain a definition for 'JSContext' and no extension method 'JSContext' accepting a first argument of type Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser could be found'..What Am I missing?..

Comment: Starting in version 22, you'll need browser.Window.JSContext.

Comment: In version 45 it's just `browser.Window`

Comment: i didnt found that way in vb.net any clue? @JohnHatton

Comment: @gumuruh Don't know what to tell you about vb.net. You can see current c# examples in the [v45 unit tests](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0/src/e8f5556a5c02381184d312492962bd169ec3a401/GeckofxUnitTests/GeckoWebBrowserTests.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Answer (score 3):

for the new versions instead of **geckoWebBrowser1.JSContext** you should write **geckoWebBrowser1.Window**

my code is working and I've answered with sample in another old post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009473/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-c-sharp-using-the/53955682#53955682)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigate method to avoid AccessViolatoinException during calling document js function:

```
webView.Navigate("javascript:$$external.consoleLog('message text');");
```