# GeckoFX JSContext not found C#

Tags: c#, javascript, geckofx

Im trying to inject javascript into my GeckoFX Browser by using the following code..

```
GeckoWebBrowser browser = ....;
using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(browser.JSContext))
{                               
   string result;
   context.EvaluateScript("3 + 2;", out result)
}
```

From another SO post found here: [How Can Execute Javascript Commands via GeckoFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803409/how-can-execute-javascript-commands-via-geckofx)

But I get an error:

'Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'JSContext' and no extension method 'JSContext' accepting a first argument of type 'Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Fairly new to C# and Im not quite sure what Im missing? Ive been searching and troubleshooting for hours and have not found a solution as to what Im overlooking and or missing. Would greatly appreciate if someone shined some light on this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that in version 22, the JSContext has been moved down a level, to the Window.

So now you'll want

```
using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(browser.Window.JSContext))
```

I found this in the [new unit tests](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-22.0/src/43eb4cb291167a3c21aa0ef63605b18a6862f3f4/GeckofxUnitTests/GeckoWebBrowserTests.cs?at=default#cl-244).

Comment: Perfect! Spent hours trying to figure this out. I got it working now. Thanks!